# Whats is this Objective C code doing?

Tags: objective-c

I am learning Objective C . I was given a code to fix that I have fixed but not entirely sure what was going on though. Can some please explain what is following code doing.

```
 //in header file  there is this line
 @property (retain) NSMutableArray *anArray;  

  // In implementation file in a method
  self.anArray = [NSMutableArray array];
  //This assigns a large value to index . What is this value. Does NSIteger needs initialization I think default is 0 
  NSInteger _nextIndex = (NSInteger)[self.anArray];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're typecasting the pointer pointing to `self.anArray` to an `NSInteger`. In other words, `_nextIndex` contains the address at which `self.anArray` is stored.

Answer (score 7):

That code is invalid, it will fail to parse `[self.anArray]`.

The square brackets are used to call methods, but there is no method you are calling. It seems like what you wan to do is `NSInteger _nextIndex = (NSInteger)[self.anArray count];` which will assign to `_nextIndex` the number of elements in the array, which is the position of the next index.

An array is a list of items, starting by 0. So, if the list doesn't have anything the `count` method will return `0`, which is the first position. If the list has 100 items, they will use indexes from `0` to `99`, then the `count` will return `100` and the next item position will be `100`.